# Key-value from long list of similar items

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a list of Python dictionaries which looks like this:

```py
[{'actual': 4.99, 'estimate': 4.55, 'period': '2019-12-31', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}, 
 {'actual': 3.03, 'estimate': 2.84, 'period': '2019-09-30', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}, 
 {'actual': 2.18, 'estimate': 2.1,  'period': '2019-06-30', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}]
```

I need to extract the actual and estimate values for each period. Then I need to divide these values by each other.

Comment: can you post your code? to see how can we help you?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
val_list = [{'actual': 4.99, 'estimate': 4.55, 'period': '2019-12-31', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}, 
{'actual': 3.03, 'estimate': 2.84, 'period': '2019-09-30', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}, 
{'actual': 2.18, 'estimate': 2.1, 'period': '2019-06-30', 'symbol': 'AAPL'}];

print([(index, val['actual']/val['estimate']) for index, val in enumerate(val_list) ])
```

Comment: Thanks. It does divide but how do we associate each with the correspondent period?

Comment: use this ```print([(index, val['actual']/val['estimate']) for index, val in enumerate(val_list) ])```

instead of ```print([val['actual']/val['estimate'] for val in val_list ])```

Comment: It will be helpful i hope.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way:
print('\n',"Period:" ,val['period'],"\n\tActual/Estimate=", val['actual'] / val['estimate'])